# Generate DITA xml from docstring

Tags: python, documentation, restructuredtext, dita

I need to document my project using [DITA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Information_Typing_Architecture) and I'm wondering if I can use python's docstring conventions and `reStructuredText` to create DITA's XMLs.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to be a bit late to this question, but I've done some work along these lines and put the resulting kit into this repository:

https://github.com/donrday/rst2dita

I hope there is something there that you or others can make use of.

Comment: Interesting. I no longer work in this project and ended up including the DITA into inline commentos (sucha a PITA). I'll recommend this nevertheless. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you could do is that

- You process your Python docstrings using [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) and its [autodoc](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html) syntax
- You write custom output formatter to Sphinx which will generate DITA XML instead of HTML

Some work, but doable.

Comment: I do not know DITA but if it is similar to plain XML one can use the sphinx builtin [XMLbuilder](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/builders.html?highlight=custom%20output%20format#sphinx.builders.xml.XMLBuilder)  with `sphinx-build -b xml ...` to produce XML output which can usually processes and converted easily to a custom format. If that is not suitable one can use the [Sphinx's Builder API](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/extdev/builderapi.html?highlight=output%20format#builder-api) to add custom builders as [extension](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/extensions.html#extensions).